# Celery, add_consumer for only specific workers

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery setup with RabbitMQ as the backend. There are different types workers doing different tasks and they are all on the same virtual host. For one specific type of worker I am using add_consumer/cancel_consumer directive in code. But doing this causes all of the workers to start/stop listening on a queue. The options that I was able to find was:

1. Get a list of workers via workers, regex partial match the worker names and use the result as the destination argument in add_consumer.
2. Isolate this worker type in a separate virtual host. It looks like creating a separate virtual host for different celery projects is a good practice. But I am not sure it is a good practice to have 2 virtual hosts for the same celery project.

Is there any other way to do this in celery?

Comment: 3rd option: Make those type of workers listen to a broadcast exchange. Publish the add_consumer / cancel_consumer queue message on this exchange and each worker starts/stops listening on the specified queue one by one.

Comment: Before starting a worker, you should give a name to worker using `-n worker_name`, So you can use this name as destination argument in add_consumer/cancel_consumer

Comment: that's how option 1 is working.